# Is recursion a bad thing, and is there a clearer or more efficient way of solving problems where recursion seems most useful?

Tags: c++, recursion, visual-studio-2013

(This problem is taken from IEEE Xtreme 2013 problem AS)

The problem I have to solve is as follows:
I am given a series of letters, consisting of pairs of joined crossroads, such as the below

```
F G
F H
H I
H J
I K
J K
G H
G I
```

The task is to navigate from one given letter to another, such as from F to K. In this case the optimum path would be F, H, I, K (i.e. the shortest path (or one of them)).

Part of the task is to find all possible paths. As the length of the path is variable, along with the number of crossroads and the number of crossroads joined to each crossroad, I reasoned I would need a variable level of nested loops - a new nested level of loop for each step along the path, along with the ability to step back along the path and go in a different direction.

the only way I could think of solving this was by creating a function, passing it an incomplete path, search for a joined letter, and have the function call itself until it reaches the end of the path, whereupon it steps back to a previous crossroads and goes in a different direction.

Is the recursion here a bad idea, or inefficient? is there a better/simpler/clearer way of solving this problem?

Code: (It doesn't quite run yet, I'm not finished with it)
(The recursive function is pathfind)

```
// Problem_AS (ice cream route finder).cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

//typdefs
typedef vector<char> route;
//each route when found will be put into a vector of routes

//function declarations
bool checkChar(vector<char>& chars, const char& c);

vector<char> create_turnings(vector<string>& pairs);

vector<char> find_joined(const char& a, vector<string>& routes);

void pathfind(const vector< vector<char> >& joined, const char& current, const char& dest, vector<char>& non_option,
    vector<route>& routes, const vector<char>& turnings, route& current_route);


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char dest;
    cin >> dest;
    char start = 'f';
    vector<string> joined;
    const string a_a = "a a";
    char input[4];
    do
    {
        cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));
        if (input != a_a)
            joined.push_back(input);


    } while (input != a_a);



    vector<char> turnings = create_turnings(joined);
    //alpabetic list of all the turns

    /*vector<char>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = turnings.begin(); iter < turnings.end(); iter++)
    {
    cout << *iter << endl;
    }*/

    //dir is a vector of string vectors - for each letter, there will be a vector, containing all the
    //letters that can be reached from the current letter
    vector < vector<char> > dir;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < turnings.size(); i++)
    {
        dir.push_back(find_joined(turnings[i], joined));

        cout << turnings[i] << ": ";

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dir[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << dir[i][j] << ", ";
        }
        cout << endl; 
    }


    vector<char> non_option;
    //will be passed to functions, contains all the letters that have been used or should not be
    route current_route; //contains the current path

    vector< route > routes; //vector of all valid paths

    pathfind(dir,start, dest, non_option, routes, turnings, current_route);



    getchar();
    return 0;
}


//checks if char c is present in the character array chars
bool checkChar(vector<char>& chars, const char& c)
{

    vector<char>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = chars.begin(); iter < chars.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (*iter == c)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}



//converts a string vector of pattern:
//"g t"
//"t y"
//"d t"
//etc into a char vector in alphabetic order (containing no repeated characters)
//the first entry in pairs is skipped, as it is empty
vector<char> create_turnings(vector<string>& pairs)
{
    vector<char> a;
    a.push_back(pairs[1][0]);
    if (!checkChar(a, pairs[1][2]))
        a.push_back(pairs[1][2]);
    vector<string>::iterator iter;
    //do first action so that check char in loop has something to check against

    for (iter = pairs.begin() + 2; iter < pairs.end(); iter++)
    {
        if (!checkChar(a, (*iter)[0]))
            a.push_back((*iter)[0]);
        if (!checkChar(a, (*iter)[2]))
            a.push_back((*iter)[2]);
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    return a;
}


//takes a letter in the map, and finds all the letters associated with it, and outputs them in a char vector
//(alpthabetcially)
vector<char> find_joined(const char& a, vector<string>& pairs)
{
    vector<char> joined;
    vector<string>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = pairs.begin()+1; iter < pairs.end(); iter++) // must skip first element as it is an empty string
    {
        if ((*iter)[0] == a)
            joined.push_back((*iter)[2]);
        if ((*iter)[2] == a)
            joined.push_back((*iter)[0]);
        //must check is the letter we are finding associations for on the left or right of the route - the opposite 
        //side of the joined letters will be added
    }
    sort(joined.begin(), joined.end());
    return joined;
}



void pathfind(const vector< vector<char> >& joined, const char& current, const char& dest, vector<char>& non_option, 
    vector<route>& routes, const vector<char>& turnings, route& current_route)
{

    current_route.push_back(current);
    non_option.push_back(current);

    //find the index of current in turnings
    unsigned int index;
    for (index = 0; index < turnings.size(); index++)
    {
        if (turnings[index] == current)
            break;
    }
    int x = joined[index].size();

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if (checkChar(non_option, joined[index][i]))
            continue;
        //check if the character being checked has been makred as a non option already 
        if (joined[index][i] == dest)
        {
            current_route.push_back(joined[index][i]);
            routes.push_back(current_route);
            continue;
        }
        //check if the character being checked is the destination, in which case mark a route

        pathfind(joined, joined[index][i], dest, non_option, routes, turnings, current_route);

        while (non_option.size() != current_route.size())
        {
            non_option.pop_back();
        }
    }
    while (non_option.size() != current_route.size())
    {
        non_option.pop_back();
    }
    current_route.pop_back();

}
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of code for what should be pretty simple. What's your problem here? Is this a code-review situation?

Comment: As its an IEEE competition problem, things that seem simple rarely are. Most path finding algorithms can take advantage of position, which doesn't work here. 
This question, I suppose, is about code format review, but its also a question about whether recursion is generally something to be avoided

Comment: Ah, that explains. Still, unless you have a specific *problem* to solve, this is not really the place for it. Which algorithm are you using for pathfinding?

Comment: Point taken. I was trying to ask is there a better way of doing this, is this not the correct place for this question? My apologies if so. 
The algorithm is my own, brute search: try every path, find every route

Comment: How long can this list become (order of magnitude)?

Comment: This is a bit long to read, but in answer to the first part of the header of your question: no. Stroustrup, in his C++ book, quotes someone else as saying "...To recurse is divine."

Comment: @MikeMB The cross roads are limited to the letters F to Z, so 21 total

Comment: Then recursion should definitely not be a problem here.

Comment: can you not simply use a breadth first search here? Seems like a simple graph problem.

Comment: @RedAlert After a brief trip to wikipedia, I believe that is in fact what I have implemented - my question is about the way of implementing this solution

Comment: At least assuming you only want an optimal path, you do *not* need to navigate all paths to solve this problem. In particular, once you've found *one* answer, you can abandon the search along another path as soon as that path's length exceeds the length of your best solution so far.

Comment: @JerryCoffin As I mentioned in the description, the task was to find the optimal path, as well as *all* paths

Comment: @Mauvai: Maybe I'm just slow, but it wasn't apparent to me that this was a requirement rather than what you'd thought of something you'd need to do to meet the requirement.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Nope, I'm aware that paths lengths exceeding my current path are no good, as well as certain letters being marked as far from the destination, and so on. But again, I mentioned specifically that I was required to find all paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to the question, but without specific reference to the code given:

**Is recursion a bad thing?**

In general, No.

**What are the trade-offs?**

Often using recursion boils down to simplicity of implementation versus simpicity of debugging and flexibility of changing implementations.

**General factors around recursive / non-recursive implementations:**

Judging by the number of questions that crop-up on StackOverflow regarding recursion, it's pretty clear that recursive code is harder to follow for many developers, partly because the code-path isn't always obvious. A non-recursive function is often easier to debug... you can step through the code and examine your stack easily without having to track which invocation of the method you're at.

However, removing recursion can sometimes make code more complex... often you have to introduce your own stack and do a bit of housekeeping that isn't necessary with recursive code.

I frequently see posters on Stack Overflow using recursion when a simple iteration would suffice such as traversing a list (no stack needed). In these trivial cases recursion should definitely be avoided (unless its a requirement of your assignment). In more comlex cases, the *performance* differences between a recursive solution and a non-recursive one usually aren't significant.

And although recursion itself *isn't* bad, one consideration is that because the size of the stack is limited by your environment you have an arbitrary limit imposed on you for the amount of recursive calls. If you know that the termination condition for your calls is met quickly then by all means recurse. If you're working with very large data sets, and potentially deep recursion, exercise caution and favour a non-recursive implementation.

Whenever you are thinking about a recursive solution (*or any algorithm for that matter*), favour clarity, readability and easy debugging first, only optimise when performance profiling shows there's a problem. Try to keep code encapsulated so implementations can be easily swapped out.

Answer (score 1):

The recursion in not always a bad idea, however there's a problem with using a recursion which is the stack depth. If your recursion goes too deep - you run out of stack and your program will not work properly. Stack depth can change from system to system, may or may not be adjustable, and stack overruns may or may not lead to an immediate crash.

If you're considering a recursion of bounded depth that you know is within the limits of your stack - go for it, it is the easier way to write code.

If you're considering recursion with unbounded depth (i.e.: you don't know how big the input can be and how many calls you're going to make) - you better implement it iteratively (i.e.: without using the OS stack, use your own structures to manage the state).

There are also ways to make recursions more efficient wrt the stack usage (for example - [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)).

In this particular case, the input doesn't seem to be too large, and I'd expect the recursion to work. If it doesn't - it is more likely to be a bug in your algorithm/implementation, rather than an inherent "recursion problem".

Comment: Is the stack depth really a concern? I have never had any problems with it and I remember me testing sorting algorithms with big-ass input. Have you ever had a problem with it?

Comment: @khajvah most definitely. It depends on implementation, if you used tail-recursion - you wouldn't worry about stack as each call will not create a new frame.